# TextView expand on Runtime

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a text box and an ImageView right of this TextVIew. I make the VISIBILITY of this Image view to GONE if Image URL not available. Now I want to expand the TextView width to MatchParent. But its not working. Something is wrong and I cant figure it out. Need help. Code is as under...

I tried with all the solutions in StackOverflow but something is really not working.

Please help.

```
                if (ImageURL.equals(null)){
            holder.Image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)
//            holder.question.setLayoutParams();
//            layoutParams.width = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            holder.question.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
//            holder.question.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and not need set layout param

> ```
>     <TextView
>         android:layout_width="0dp"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent"
>         android:layout_weight="10"
>         android:text="sadasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdsadasdasd" />
>
>     <ImageView
>         android:layout_width="0dp"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent"
>         android:layout_weight="3"
>         android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
>         android:visibility="visible" />
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Constraint layout is more flexible for this situation. Use of `RelativeLayout` is not encouraged anymore.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"/>

    <ImageView
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

To make the `TextView` take the entire width simply change the `visibility` of the `ImageView` to `GONE`.

```
imageView.visibility = GONE
```